# Automatic @since javadoc tag for releases

Tags: java, javadoc, documentation-generation

Is there a tool to automatically add the @since tag to all elements when I want to have a release version?

So let's say I have a bunch of methods and my base system is working now, so I decide to release it as version 0.1.0

What I want now is a tool that searches for every missing @since tag and adds it accordingly.

I'm using Eclipse and I have found JAutodoc, but as far as I can see it only allows to search for the missing tags and I'd have to add them manually.

EDIT:
One workaround that might be interesting for someone: From the beginning on use an Eclipse Template with the right since tag and after each release change the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like something your build tool should provide you with. If you are using maven you should have a look at javadoc:fix. It looks like it does exactly what you want:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/fix-mojo.html

Comment: I did try to look into maven a while ago. At first it looked very promising and it still does. But till now I never managed to get it to work. Anyway, from next month on I hope to have some more time and will have a look again. Thus thanks so far!

Answer (score 0):

Can I just add a lesson I learned about 27 years ago: don't try to make your version control numbers align with your product release numbers. That way madness lies.

Comment: Well the problem is: If your API is public and others are useing it and you have different releases and not everyone has the latest, than it's a good thing to let people know if they can use a specific method or not.
Or do you have a better solition? I'm always open ;D